# How to unban my IP for Recaptcha error: "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again."

Tags: networking, ip, recaptcha

My home ip is constantly getting the recaptcha error: **Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.**

From my reseach Google bans IPs which is why I'm getting this error. Is there a solution to remove this banned ip from Google recaptcha?

Only solution thus far is just change my ip by using a hotspot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that this error message pops up if the "Google Recaptcha" logo is shown on the page yet, which can be caused from a slow page load if the logo is hidden. Make sure the logo is shown on the page.

Comment: Not the solution. We have had working captchas when logo is not showing, and not working captchas with this error when it is showing.